# Regex greedy parse direction

Tags: java, javascript, python, regex, perl

I found there're two different opinions about how greedy regex is executed:

- one is, read all the input string and match the pattern from the back, first match entire input,the first attempt is entire string. Some articles support this opinion are [Oracle offical Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html):

> Greedy quantifiers are considered "greedy" because they force the
>   matcher to read in, or eat, the entire input string prior to
>   attempting the first match. If the first match attempt (the entire
>   input string) fails, the matcher backs off the input string by one
>   character and tries again, repeating the process until a match is
>   found or there are no more characters left to back off from.

also see this article: [Performance of Greedy vs. Lazy Regex Quantifiers](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance)

- the other is matching from the front, the first match attempt is from the 0 index in the left. when a match is found, the engine doesn't stop, keep matching the rest until it fails then it'll backtrack. Articles supports this opinion I found is:

[Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) the  `Looking Inside The Regex Engine` section talk about `<.+>`:

> The first token in the regex is <. This is a literal. As we already
>   know, the first place where it will match is the first < in the
>   string.

I want to know which one is correct? This matters because it will affect the efficiency of regex. I added various language tags, because I want to know if it's implemented differently in each language.

Comment: Both articles tell the same thing. i mean, your first bullet point. Read `Repetition ...` link again.

Comment: do you have a regexp you'd like us to examine? would you like to profile various regexps?

Comment: @Prince John Wesley yes, both articles in the first bullet point, have the same opinion, the question is someone have different opinions like in the second bullet point and I don't know which one should follow.

Comment: Which link says the second bullet point, the last link `Repetition with Star and Plus` says the first bullet point.

Comment: `keep matching the rest until it fails then it'll backtrack` - how will the parser know the match failure until it eat everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The matcher backs off the input string by one character and tries again" is just describing backtracking, so "then it'll backtrack" is therefore saying the same thing. Since both of your quotes regarding greediness say the same thing, both are correct. (Your third quote has nothing to do with greediness.)

---

Let's provide an example.

```
'xxabbbbbxxabbbbbbbbb' =~ /([ab]*)bb/;
```

1. Try at pos 0.

   1. `[ab]*` matches 0 chars "".

      1. At pos 0, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   2. `[ab]*` can't match any less ⇒ Backtrack.
2. Try at pos 1.

   1. `[ab]*` matches 0 chars "".

      1. At pos 1, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   2. `[ab]*` can't match any less ⇒ Backtrack.
3. Try at pos 2.

   1. `[ab]*` matches 6 chars "`abbbbb`".

      1. At pos 8, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   2. `[ab]*` matches 5 chars "`abbbb`". (Back off one)

      1. At pos 7, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   3. `[ab]*` matches 4 chars "`abbb`". (Back off one)

      1. At pos 6, `bb` matches.

         1. Success.

So $1 is "abbb". (Not `abbbbbbb`. "Greedy" doesn't mean "longest match possible".)

---

Now, let's see what happens if we make the "*" non-greedy.

```
'xxabbbbbxxabbbbbbbbb' =~ /([ab]*?)bb/;
```

1. Try at pos 0.

   1. `[ab]*?` matches 0 chars "".

      1. At pos 0, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   2. `[ab]*` can't match any more ⇒ Backtrack.
2. Try at pos 1.

   1. `[ab]*?` matches 0 chars "".

      1. At pos 1, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   2. `[ab]*` can't match any more ⇒ Backtrack.
3. Try at pos 2.

   1. `[ab]*?` matches 0 chars "".

      1. At pos 2, `bb` fails to match ⇒ Backtrack.
   2. `[ab]*?` matches 1 char "`a`". (Add one)

      1. At pos 3, `bb` matches.

         1. Success.

So $1 is "a".

---

Specific implementation might do things differently as an optimisation, as long as it gives the same result as presented here. You can see Perl at work using

```
perl -Mre=debug -E'say "xxabbbbbxxabbbbbbbbb" =~ /([ab]*)bb/;'
perl -Mre=debug -E'say "xxabbbbbxxabbbbbbbbb" =~ /([ab]*?)bb/;'
```

Comment: thank you. All the inputs are evaluated from left to right and matched against the pattern right? the first quote seems to me that, it match the 'xxabbbbbxxabbbbbbbbb' first (it said match entire string) and then one letter less from right 'xxabbbbbxxabbbbbbbb', looks like matching from the right to the left.

Comment: They both say "if `bb` doesn't match, reduce what `[ab]*` matched by one" as I showed. It steps back through what `[ab]*` matched, from `abbbbb` to `abbbb` to `abbb`. That's how one backtracks through `X*`. Again, both quotes say exactly the same thing.

Comment: sorry, don't really mean to be so annoying, just can't understand in the first quote `If the first match attempt (the entire input string) fails`, you see the first attempt is the entire string, but in your example the first attempt is position 0, that's the only thing confuses me.

Comment: @Sawyer, I guess I overlooked "the entire input string" part because it makes no sense. You only backtrack over what the X* expression matches. They must be talking about a match consisting of just `.*`.

Comment: @Sawyer, I specifically marked "Back off one" where it backs off as mentioned in the quote.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they're functionally equivalent (and based on my Java regex use, they are), it's just a difference in engine implementation. Regular Expressions are not implemented exactly the same way in all languages, and can be more or less powerful based on which language you use.

The second link describes Perl, so I'd trust Oracle on the Java side of things.

Both attempt to get the *largest* match possible.

Making a quantifier lazy by adding the `?` key will attempt the *smallest* match possible.

Comment: To the person who left a downvote, do you mind clarifying what I should improve?

Comment: No, adding `?` doesn't attempt to find the smallest match. e.g. `'abbaba' =~ /a(b*?)a/` gives `bb` and not `b`. Similar, not using `?` doesn't attempt to find the largest match. e.g. `'ababba' =~ /a(b*)a/` gives `b` and not `bb`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of regex in differenet envronments and programming languages does not have to be same, so there is no exact answer to your question.

If you go with **Perl**, then you should know that **regex** implementation **is** very **optimized**, as this is one of the strongest feature of this programming language. So, don't worry about efficiency :)

Comment: perl uses a backtracking RE implementation, which is usually fast but has some really pathological worst-case behavior.  the `perlre` docs have more specifics on this.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a difference, and there's no "matching from the back" implied. When the first reference says "the matcher", it means the repeated regex atom, not the entire expression — i.e. when matching `/ab+/` against "abbot", we don't know *a priori* that the `b+` won't match the entire rest of the string. I think that the Java tutorial might be discussing the behavior of regex matching against *streams*, and noting that a greedy repetition will eagerly consume the rest of the stream, while a nongreedy repetition will lazily consume the stream as needed.